# behaviour of learning curve unexpectedly changing when I execute whole notebook again and again

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, logistic-regression, kaggle

I am new at machine learning. I participated in kaggle competition[ https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic ] in which we are given some data about passengers of titanic and we are supposed to predict a person would survive or not. So I use logistic regression to predict whether a person will survive or not. My score is 0.77511 / 1.000 so I was wondering that what's wrong with it. So I visualize the learning curve so that I can get an intuition. When I plot the learning curve the first time curve was as expected(not expected but acceptable) but when I execute my jupyter notebook again learning curve just drastically changed(neither expected nor acceptable). It looks like randomly follows the nature of the learning curve. why is it so? can someone explain why it is happening?? here it is my code notebook [ https://www.kaggle.com/cookie98/titanic-logistic-regression ] check learning curve by clicking "Run All" again and again.

[image: learning curve when first time run notebook][image: learning curve when second time run notebook]

Comment: The Kaggle link you've provided is unusable, even after removing the trailing `]`.

Comment: sorry for that...!! please check it again.